Can't run X server on read-only system
I'm trying to prevent a small SBC storage medium from getting wasted by continuous write activities, and at the same time achieve a functioning GUI. Using alpine in sys/classic mode (I have very low RAM available).
Simplest way to accomplish that appears to be mounting the root partition as read-only by default.
xorg is the main thing causing me problems with this. If ~/.Xauthority is locked, it won't startx. If it somehow (doesn't happen every time, maybe it's interval-based) wants to retire its old log file, it will completely refuse to start with a "fatal error". And these files don't play nice with symlinks. 
Is it possible to configure X11 to place/expect these files in a special directory rather than ~ and /var/log respectively? Or stuff them into a tiny tmpfs playing nice with the scarce RAM? Or simply turn off logging for X11 completely?
Another side issue I have with this approach is that udhcpd always wants to mess with /etc/resolv.conf on boot by creating an /etc/resolv.conf.somenumber (likely a PID), then probably merging it with the main file. This is just creating warnings though, no actual errors.

I suspect getting X to start will just be the start of your pain. I'd suggest using a RAM disk + overlayFS - a quick goolge turned up step-by-step instructions here: https://github.com/nils-werner/raspi-overlayroot

You can use the XAUTHORITY env var. (Actually if you are talking about the Xorg log, rootless X should use ~/.local/share/xorg; even though my system root is not read-only, I still have ~/.local/share/xorg being a symlink that points to /run/user/$uid.)

With that said, I'm not so sure that you can/should have the whole /var being read-only anyway though...
